# Artifactory and gradle, jenkins build space issue

Tags: jenkins, artifactory

I work on our project build and deployment process using gradle, Jenkins and artifactory server.I am currently facing a space issue on our server. I looked through the artifactory folder on my server, the artifactory/data/filestore size is @59GB.Though I don't think our projects need jars of so much size. Can anybody help how to reduce the filestore size and any impact of it on project build?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are various reasons which can cause Artifactory storage space to grow:

1. Not cleaning up unused snapshot versions
2. [Garbage collection](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Regular+Maintenance+Operations#RegularMaintenanceOperations-GarbageCollection) not running frequent enough or not running at all
3. Unused 3rd part dependencies piling up

You should start by going over [Managing Disk Space Usage](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Managing+Disk+Space+Usage) in the Artifactory manual. It covers topics such as garbage collection, deleting unused artifacts, manual cleanup and others.

**Update**

In case most of the artifacts that are consuming the storage are release artifacts, you need to decide whether you need to store all off them or can move them to another place.
By release artifacts I means artifacts that have passed your CI pipeline and are ready for production, those can be:

- Artifacts deployed in production (private/public cloud)
- Release version of libraries/modules being used by other projects
- Products/Libraries distributed to customers

As long as such artifacts are required, for example because other teams depends on them for development, you should keep them where they are. If they are not being used any more but you need to keep a copy of them you may want to move them to another Artifactory server which will serve as an archive.

**Update 2**

For deleting artifacts you can use one of the following methods:

1. Use the [delete item](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-DeleteItem) REST API for deleting artifacts/folders
2. Use the [delete builds](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-DeleteBuilds) REST API for deleting complete builds. This is useful if you are using the Artifactory [build integration](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Build+Integration)
3. Create a custom cleanup [user plugin](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/User+Plugins). You can see some examples in [Github](https://github.com/JFrogDev/artifactory-user-plugins/tree/master/cleanup). This requires Artifactory Pro.

Comment: I have tried all those options, but none of them are reducing the space.The libs-release-local repository which is increasing with every build.It is currently occcupied by @60GB.How to optimize/reduce this size?

Comment: Are you storing only release artifacts in libs-release-local? do you need to keep all of them or you can move them to an archive (maybe on another Artifactory instance)?

Comment: How to identify if it is storing only release artifacts?I dont need all of them.So i can archieve them

Comment: Thanks for the answer,I was going through the lib-release-local tree browser, it has folder like com-<projectname>-1.0.1,1.0.2 etc like that till 1.0.311. Is it possible to delete all version except last 10. Same is application to other projects also.

Comment: Just to update, In artifacts->Tree Browser->Repository Browser->libs-release-local->select each folder like - com-<web>-<1.0.1> and delete version .Is there any automated way using gradle script which can be used to delete old build?

Comment: Thanks drorb, I guess this is what I have been looking.

Comment: I am trying to use the REST API in gradle, but it is not working.Can anybody point to some example of deleting build using project name and build number using REST API in gradle script?

Comment: @hanmayya take a look at the [rest-gradle-plugin](https://github.com/noamt/rest-gradle-plugin) it provides a task infrastructure to perform REST requests